# How to capture stacktrace of failing test in extent report for specflow

Tags: visual-studio, specflow, extentreports

I want to capture stacktrace of failed scenario for specflow

In my extent report I have

```
scenario.CreateNode<Then>(scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(scenarioContext.TestError.StackTrace)
```

It is capturing stacktrace but I want to display them like it comes on visual studio to make it more user readable. How can I do that.

VisualStudio:[image] Here line no , file is clearly mentioned

ExtentReport :[image] Here line is mentioned but not user needs to find it.

Comment: Is the stack trace appearing on a single line in the report? Is that the issue?

Comment: Also, it appears there is a syntax error in the code in your question. Can you correct that? `scenario.CreateNode<Then(` --- the opening parenthesis appears to be in the wrong spot.

Comment: It seems to be that  different info is printed in stacktrace. for visual studio it seems to be coming from specflow itself like info abt test engine and line no from feature file is also mentioned while in extent report it is more from nunit assert

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to replace all newline characters with `<br>` HTML tags. Maybe this will format the stack trace with multiple lines:

```cs
scenario.CreateNode<Then>(scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text)
        .Fail(scenarioContext.TestError.StackTrace.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>"));
```

---

<sub>Note: I haven't used Extent Reports, so I'm not sure if you will see each line in the stack trace on its own line in the report, or if you will see the `<br>` tags rendered as text on screen.</sub>